# What does the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() refer to in a nested Task?

Tags: .net, asynchronous

If I create and start a task and call

```
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
```

I know that, in WPF, it refers to the GUI thread. If I create a nested Task within that task and call this method, will it still refer to the same GUI thread? I think this method calls the TaskScheduler and retrieves a static variable that refers to the GUI. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to whatever `SynchronizationContext` is installed on the thread you call this method on. When you call it on the thread pool this usually will be `null`. If you call it on the UI thread it's the UI thread context.

So it depends on what scheduler your parent task runs on.

Also, your code could have modified `SynchronizationContext.Current` but that is rare.

All of this has nothing to do with tasks. It's about how the current thread is configured.

Comment: So, if I nest a task within another task and call FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), then it will return null?

Comment: `it depends on what scheduler your existing task runs on` existing = parent task.